# Это слово, словосочетание или предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, словосочетания

"Анна Каренина", "Борис Годунов" и другие подобные структуры, построенные по схеме "имя+фамилия", в изолированном виде являются словом, словосочетанием или предложением?

Comment: Допускаете, что "Борис Годунов" — это предложение?

Comment: Это что... Вот как насчёт испанских имён?! Они могут быть не то что предложением – повестью!

Comment: "Борис! "
Это ведь предложение

Comment: Надеюсь, "словом" это не бывает. А вот если точка или, не дай Бог, ещё какой знак стоит... кто ж докажет, что нет здесь неполного предложения? :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Анна Каренина, Борис Годунов — это имена собственные, выраженные **сочетанием**  имени и фамилии. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=67

В тексте такие структуры могут выполнять различные функции.

Грамматическая справка:

Собственное имя существительное — это **слово или словосочетание**, предназначенное для названия предмета, выделяющее этот предмет  из  ряда однотипных предметов.

Comment: то, что это имена собственные, понятно.
А вне текста, что это?

Comment: Вечер перестаёт быть томным.

Comment: Существуют три основных структурных единицы: слово, словосочетание и предложение. У слова  и словосочетания - назывная  функция,  у предложения - коммуникативная функция (общение, передача мыслей). Строго говоря, сочетания бывают разные: с подчинительной связью, с сочинительной связью и предикативные сочетания (подлежащее + сказуемое).

Comment: .Мы привыкли считать, что имя существительное - это слово, и это верно для нарицательных существительных.  А собственное существительное может являться словосочетанием, и это ОСОБОЕ словосочетание, так как оно называет ОДИН ПРЕДМЕТ (как и слово), то есть  это сочетание с особой функцией.

Comment: А вот структура такого сочетания  соотносится с подчинительной связью (в данных примерах даже имеет место согласование в падеже), так как русские фамилии часто соответствуют  притяжательным прилагательным, в других случаях    такая связь строится на основе примыкания. И вывод: Анна Каренина - это особое словосочетание, выполняющее номинативную функцию одного слова.

Answer (score 2):

Словосочетанием принято называть два самостоятельных слова, связанные подчинительной связью (иногда с использованием служебного слова - предлога). Сочетание имени и фамилии, строго говоря, не является словосочетанием.Это сочетание двух отдельных слов. При указании выходных сведений издания между ними даже ставится запятая. Например: Хемингуэй, Эрнест.

Comment: Сочетание двух отдельных слов - это особая структура? А какова природа связи между ними?

Comment: Это не особая структура, это две единицы языка, два слова, а вместе - имя собственное. Имена собственные могут быть словом, словосочетанием, слитным сочетанием, а это свободное сочетание двух отдельных слов.

Comment: Свободное сочетание - это и есть особая структура.  Только непонятно, что это означает, как именно они сочетаются. Просто рядом стоят или как-то связаны.